# Proving if $|G|=280$, then $G$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra

So $280 = 2^3\cdot 5 \cdot 7$. I assume $G$ is simple. I'm having trouble using the Sylow Theorems to show that this is not Simple. In particular, computing the number of sylow groups and using that to show the group isn't Simple.

Comment: What possible numbers did you come up with for the various Sylow subgroups?

Comment: Well, for $n_2$, we would have $n_2 \equiv 1 mod 3$ and $n_2 \mid 45$ right? Then $n_2 = 7$ is the only number that satisfies this. But then for $n_5$, I think I am messing up. I say $n_5 \equiv 1 mod 1$ and $n_5 \mid 56$. But $1 mod 1$ does't make any sense

Comment: You are doing mod the wrong thing. It should be mod the given prime, not mod the exponent.

Comment: Ah, whoops. So $n_2 \equiv 1 \mod{2}$ and $n_2 \mid 45$ which means $n_2 = \{1,5,7\}$. $n_5 \equiv 1 \mod{5} $ and $n_5 \mid 56$, but there are no $n_5$ which satisfies this except $1$. For $n_7 \equiv 1 \mod{7}$ and $n_7 \mid 40$ then $n_7 = \{1,8\}$.

Comment: @Algnoe Where in the world are you taking that poor $\;45\;$ from... *again* ??

Comment: Multiply is hard, $n_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $n_2 \mid 35$ which mean $n_2 = \{1,5,7\}$

Comment: @Algnoe In fact, $\;n_2\in\{1,\,5,\,7,\,7\cdot5=35\}\;$ . I hope your remark on multiplication was jesty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the group isn't simple $\;\implies n_5=56\implies\;$ there are $\;56\cdot 4=224\;$ elements of order $\;5\;$

Also, we have that  $\;n_7\ge8\implies\;$ there are at least $\;8\cdot 6=48\;$ elements of order $\;7\;$ .

Thus, we already have $\;224+48=272\;$ elements of order $\;5\,\,\,or\;\;7\;$ . The ones left *must* belong to the then *unique* Sylow $\;2$-subgroup ...

**Other proof's highlights** . Suppose $\;n_5=56\;$ , then there exists a subgroup of $\;G\;$ with this order and this with index $\;\frac{280}{56}=5\;$ (namely, any Sylow $\;5$-subgroup's normalizer).

But then the action of $\;G\;$ on this subgroup's left cosets (i.e., the regular left action) renders a homomorphism $\;G\to S_5\;$ which, if $\;G\;$ is simple, **must** be injective. But this is absurd as $\;|G|\nmid 5!=120\;$ .